# Cherrypy: How get rawdata from uploaded file?

Tags: python, cherrypy

i have a problem with upload a file using cherrypy 3.2.4. (Python 2.7)
I can't get rawdata of uploaded file. I've tried to debug to find how to get data value from response but without success. Have anybody an idea how to solve this ?

Piotr

This is code which I use:

```
    def index(self):
    return """
    <html><body>
        <h2>Upload a file</h2>
        <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        filename: <input type="file" name="myFile" /><br />
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <h2>Download a file</h2>
        <a href='download'>This one</a>
    </body></html>
    """
index.exposed = True

def upload(self, myFile):
    out = """<html>
    <body>
        myFile length: %s<br />
        myFile filename: %s<br />
        myFile mime-type: %s
    </body>
    </html>"""


    cherrypy.log('-'*60)
    cherrypy.log('0: ' + str(dir(myFile)))
    cherrypy.log('-'*60)
    cherrypy.log('2: ' + str(dir(cherrypy.request.headers)))
    cherrypy.log('-'*60)
    cherrypy.log('4: ' + str(dir(cherrypy.request.rfile)))
    cherrypy.log('-'*60)
    cherrypy.log('6: ' + str(cherrypy.request.rfile.readline))
    cherrypy.log('-'*60)
    cherrypy.log('8: ' + str(cherrypy.request.rfile.read()))
    cherrypy.log('-'*60)
    cherrypy.log('-'*60)
    cherrypy.log('-'*60)
    # Although this just counts the file length, it demonstrates
    # how to read large files in chunks instead of all at once.
    # CherryPy reads the uploaded file into a temporary file;
    # myFile.file.read reads from that.
    size = 0
    while True:
        data = myFile.file.read(8192)
        if not data:
            break
        size += len(data)
    #cherrypy.log('myFile: %s' % str(dir(myFile)))
    #cherrypy.log('File: %s' % str(myFile.read_into_file))
    #myFile.read_into_file('a.txt')
    return out % (size, myFile.filename, myFile.content_type)
upload.exposed = True
```

and this is output:

```
[27/Jul/2014:13:38:32]  0: ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__module__', '__new__', '__next__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'attempt_charsets', 'boundary', 'charset', 'content_type', 'default_content_type', 'default_proc', 'file', 'filename', 'fp', 'from_fp', 'fullvalue', 'headers', 'length', 'make_file', 'maxrambytes', 'name', 'next', 'params', 'part_class', 'parts', 'process', 'processors', 'read', 'read_headers', 'read_into_file', 'read_lines_to_boundary', 'readline', 'readlines', 'type', 'value']
[27/Jul/2014:13:38:32]  2: ['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__','__weakref__', 'clear', 'copy', 'elements', 'encode', 'encode_header_items', 'encodings', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'output', 'pop', 'popitem', 'protocol', 'setdefault', 'update', 'use_rfc_2047', 'values', 'viewitems', 'viewkeys', 'viewvalues']
[27/Jul/2014:13:38:32]  4: ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__module__', '__new__', '__next__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'close', 'read', 'readline', 'readlines', 'remaining', 'rfile']
[27/Jul/2014:13:38:32]  6: <bound method KnownLengthRFile.readline of <cherrypy.wsgiserver.wsgiserver2.KnownLengthRFile object at 0x0000000002FF8D30>>
[27/Jul/2014:13:38:32]  8:
[27/Jul/2014:13:38:32] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 200 172 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0"
```

**Edited:**

I tried and found simple solution :

```
def upload(self, myFile):
    lcHDRS = {}
    for key, val in cherrypy.request.headers.iteritems():
        lcHDRS[key.lower()] = val

    incomingBytes = int(lcHDRS['content-length'])
    content = myFile.file.read(incomingBytes)
    file = open ('./upload/' + file.filename,"wb")
    file.write(content)
    file.close()                

    return 'File was uploaded...'
```

Answer (score 1):

First remove your cherrypy log statements.  Line 6 of those is erroring.  Also add these lines to your while loop...

```
size = 0

# NEW LINE
all_data = bytearray()

while True:
    data = myFile.file.read(8192)

    # NEW LINE
    all_data += data

    if not data:
        break
    size += len(data)

    # to save the file use this

    saved_file=open(myFile.filename, 'wb') 
    saved_file.write(all_data) 
    saved_file.close()

return out % (size, myFile.filename, myFile.content_type)
```

Right now you're only getting the first 8192 bytes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you  - I saw allready that your answer is almost same what I write above... I have only read file length from request header  :)